# how do i access the elmah log when used in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, elmah

I installed elmah as described here https://github.com/rdingwall/elmah-contrib-webapi

Now I am trying to access the logging but I keep getter error 404 errors. 
Am I using the correct url ? Is there still some configuration missing ?

My webapi runs as follows :
http://localhost/MagnusREST/api/Customers/054036?frmt=xml

My application_start looks like this :

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorApiAttribute()); //added for elmah
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();  
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

my webapi config remained unchanged and looks like this :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services


        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
            new QueryStringMapping("frmt", "json",
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")));

        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
            new QueryStringMapping("frmt", "xml",
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml")));

        //config.Formatters.Clear();
        JsonMediaTypeFormatter oldformatter = config.Formatters.Where(f => f is JsonMediaTypeFormatter).FirstOrDefault() as JsonMediaTypeFormatter;
        if (oldformatter != null) config.Formatters.Remove(oldformatter);
        config.Formatters.Insert(0,new PartialJsonMediaTypeFormatter() { IgnoreCase = true });
    }
}
```

Accessing logs via http://localhost/MagnusREST/api/elmah.axd does not work, via http://localhost/MagnusREST/elmah.axd does not work and http://localhost/elmah.axd does not work either.

What am I doing wrong?

This is running in visual studio 2013.

Comment: Thank you for downvoting, but if you google around this topic, the information is totally scattered and incomplete. So I think this is a viable question. I tried to be complete in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a missing piece in the web.config

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
</handlers>
```

The elma handler needs to be added. After doing that I could access the elmah log using followin url :

```
http://localhost/MagnusREST/elmah.axd
```

You have to read the documentation and questions both for elmah and the webapi contrib it seems. Ok the first problem is passed, what will be the next ;-)

To get is fully working more is needed than the above

Add configsections

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
        <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
        <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
     </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

Add the elmah configuration you like for instance to send mails :

```
<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="0" />
    <errorMail from="xxxx" to="xxx" subject="some error" async="true"
           smtpPort="25" smtpServer="xxx" userName="xxx" password="xxx"/>         
</elmah>
```

The system.web and system.webserver need to be something like this :

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <add name="Elmah.ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="Elmah.ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Take a good look where elmah is being mentioned and add those things to your own configuration file that might look slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to add this to my web.config and they it worked

```
<location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <!-- 
    See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
    more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.

  <authorization>
    <allow roles="admin" />
    <deny users="*" />  
  </authorization>
  -->
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```